# GeoPandas Convert Geometry Column To Geometry Type

Tags: python, pandas, postgis, geopandas

I currently have a geopandas dataframe that looks like this

```
|----|-------|-----|------------------------------------------------|
| id | name  | ... |                  geometry                      |
|----|-------|-----|------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | poly1 | ... | 0101000020E6100000A6D52A40F1E16690764A7D...    |
|----|-------|-----|------------------------------------------------|
| 2  | poly2 | ... | 0101000020E610000065H7D2A459A295J0A67AD2...    |
|----|-------|-----|------------------------------------------------|
```

And when getting ready to write it to postgis, I am getting the following error:

```
/python3.7/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py:1321: UserWarning: Geometry column does not contain geometry.
  warnings.warn("Geometry column does not contain geometry.")
```

Is there a way to convert this geometry column to a geometry type so that when it is appending to the existing table with geometry type column errors can be avoided. I've tried:

```
df['geometry'] = gpd.GeoSeries.to_wkt(df['geometry'])
```

But there are errors parsing the existing geometry column. Is there a correct way I am missing?

Comment: It seems that the geometry column is base64 encoded. Is it possible to have a full row of your GeoDataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax needs to be changed as below

```
df['geometry'] = df.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.wkt).apply(lambda x: re.sub('"(.*)"', '\\1', x))
```